# How to convert data table from SQL Server to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I want to download an Excel file containing the data from a SQL Server table in C#.

What is the best way to get it?

Comment: *"what is the best way to get it"* What ever is the best way for *you*. There are many options out there for you to do this, and what is best is based solely on opinion. If you do have a programming question, however, please do ask one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there is tons of options you can choose between. For most cases the easiest way is to make a CSV file also known as comma seperated file.
The idea of a CSV file is to make a line for each row of your table and seperate each column with semicolon. Example for the header string could be "id;firstname;lastname;phonenumber;". Then your file should be named *.csv. Then you open your csv file i excel or any similar program.

Comment: This doesn't tell the OP the how though.